# PL/SQL select as condition in while loop

Tags: select, plsql, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use select as condition in while loop.
I want to use while loop to compare random numbers with numbers in table09 while number is not in table09. But my script ends with errors. How can I use select as condition in while loop?
I have this code:

```
declare 
  my_idadh varchar(14);
  n number;
begin 
n:=round(dbms_random.value(10000000000000,99999999999999));
my_idadh:=to_char(n);

while exists(select idadh from table09 where idadh=my_idadh)
  loop
    n:=round(dbms_random.value(10000000000000,99999999999999));
    idadh:=to_char(n);
  end loop;
end;
```

Thanks, Peter

Comment: The exists clause only works in sql statements. Your select will need the INTO clause to get the value and then use in the while.

Answer (score 1):

you can put your query inside the loop and check the condition with a variable like this:

```
V_dummy :=1;

While (v_dummy = 1) loop

Begin

select 1
Into v_dummy
from table09 
where idadh=my_idadh

Exception when no_data_found then
Exit;
End;

-- you loop code here...

End loop;
```